# Can't set nginx static files with openshift microservice

Tags: reactjs, nginx, openshift, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a project with microservices on openshift.
one of my services uses react and I am using nginx to serve the static files.

Now let's say my DNS is https://greg.com
and my microservice path is /info/pc/

I get a 403 error of the Nginx trying to serve the files from https://greg.com/assets/index.js

this is my Nginx default.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

I have another microservice its path is /
There it works just fine.

I am guessing I need to specify the microservice's path, but I can't really find where and also how I can do it dynamically using the openshift route service and not write the string.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score -1):

To resolve the Nginx 403 error and serve the static files correctly for your microservice with the path "/info/pc/", you can update the Nginx configuration by adding a new location block specifically for that path. Here's an updated version of your Nginx default.conf:

```
events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location /info/pc/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/info/pc/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

In this configuration, the `location /info/pc/` block is added to handle requests specifically for that path. The `alias` directive specifies the file path where the static files for that microservice are located. The `try_files` directive is used to attempt to serve the requested file, and if it doesn't exist, it falls back to serving the `index.html` file.

By updating your Nginx configuration with this new location block, Nginx will be able to serve the static files for your microservice at the path "/info/pc/" without encountering the 403 error.

Regarding the dynamic configuration using the OpenShift route service, you can define the desired microservice path in the route configuration itself. By default, the OpenShift route service will handle the routing for you based on the defined paths. This way, you won't need to manually modify the Nginx configuration for each microservice path.

To configure the microservice path dynamically using the OpenShift route service, you can update the route definition in your OpenShift configuration YAML file. Here's an example:

```
yaml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: my-route
spec:
  host: greg.com
  path: /info/pc/
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: my-service
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 8080
```

In this example, the `path` field is set to "/info/pc/", which defines the desired microservice path. The `to` field specifies the target service to route the traffic to, and the `port` field specifies the target port of the service.

By updating the route configuration with the desired microservice path, the OpenShift route service will handle the routing for you, and Nginx can serve the static files correctly without the need for manual configuration changes in the Nginx default.conf file.

Comment: Hi @enthusiasticMorteza the openshift service path is something which is created automatically with my deployment, the path already exists and it works.

The problem is serving the files, I tried to change it to what you said but I get a 503 Service Unavailable and the GET request it tries to do is from https://greg.com/assets/index.js.